# ConnectionLoggingProxy.wrap(conn) causes `SQLException: Stream has already been closed` on Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

when running the following query using jdbc:

```
SELECT partition_name, high_value
FROM user_tab_partitions
WHERE table_name = 'SOME_TABLE_WITH_PARTITIONS';
```

Trying the following (In Java):

```
rs.getString("high_value");
```

Yielded the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Stream has already been closed
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.LongAccessor.getBytesInternal(LongAccessor.java:127)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.Accessor.getBytes(Accessor.java:926)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.LongAccessor.getString(LongAccessor.java:154)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedStatement.getString(GeneratedStatement.java:287)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getString(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:374)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedResultSet.getString(GeneratedResultSet.java:594)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getString(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor70.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jdbcdslog.ResultSetLoggingHandler.invoke(ResultSetLoggingHandler.java:19)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.getString(Unknown Source)
    at mypackage.MyClass.extractHighValue(MyClass.java:46)
```

* See that this question is unrelated to querying deprecated `LONG` types.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using, and what is the version of the Oracle JDBC driver?

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, we were using a wrapper for the connection for logging the queries named ([jdbcdslog](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.usc/jdbcdslog/1.0.6.2)):

```
ConnectionLoggingProxy.wrap(conn)
```

Once I removed the wrapper, everything worked, though I still don't know why `jdbcdslog` caused this issue. Bad reflection? Perhaps the integration with `hikaryCP`?